# AngularJS Route - custom validation, then check other routes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

Say I have a route like "/:department", where department can only be books, music, etc. firstly, how do I enforce this constraint **prior to controller/template selection**, and then if its not valid, how do I have it test against the other routes in he table? Otherwise, for example, /about would not be valid.

The other two components of choosing the appropriate controller and template I understand is just a matter of using functions for both that return paths built from $routeParams.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do something like this:

Suppose your route is like this :

```
.when('get/:department, {
   templateUrl: 'Your template url',
   controller: 'controller'
});
```

And in your controller:

```
app.controller('controller', function ($location, $routeParams){
    if($routeParams.department!=='books' || $routeParams.department!=='music' || .....) {
       $location.path('invalid route');
    } else {
   // Your controller body
    }
});
```

Comment: I considered that but i'm setting up a controller and template just to handle a redirect, which seems a bit hacky.